# No Button Save to Create a Shipment of Order

Tags: magento, adminhtml

I can't change state of my orders. See the problem on Image.
The Button Save to Create a Shipment of Order there isn't in page.

The order in question is already in the state processing.

Version: 1.6.2.0

[Problem http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/5984/nosavebuttonshipping.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/5984/nosavebuttonshipping.jpg)

I recover button after commented code in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml

```
<div class="order-totals-bottom">

      <?php //if ($this->canCreateShippingLabel()): ?>
      <p>
          <label class="normal" for="create_shipping_label"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Create Shipping Label') ?></label>
          <input id="create_shipping_label" name="shipment[create_shipping_label]" value="1" type="checkbox"  onclick="toggleCreateLabelCheckbox();" />
      </p>
      <?php //endif; ?>
      <p>
          <label class="normal" for="notify_customer"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Append Comments') ?></label>
          <input id="notify_customer" name="shipment[comment_customer_notify]" value="1" type="checkbox" />
      </p>
      <?php if ($this->canSendShipmentEmail()): ?>
      <p>
          <label class="normal" for="send_email"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Email Copy of Shipment') ?></label>
          <input id="send_email" name="shipment[send_email]" value="1" type="checkbox" />
      </p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="a-right">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>
      </div>
</div>
```

But why the other two options (Email Copy of Shipment AND Append Comments) doesn't appear when `$this->canCreateShippingLabel()` is NULL?

Any Ideas?

Comment: if `$this->canSendShipmentEmail()` is null then ofcourse the IF condition will evaluate false and the content inside it will not get displayed.

Comment: Sorry: canCreateShippingLabel